# Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is 'docker -d' running on this host?

Tags: docker

I am trying to run my Docker commands, but I am facing the notification error in the title. I tried running:

```
ps auxww | grep docker
```

but still getting the error. Any solution?

Comment: What is the output of `ps aux | grep docker`? What command exactly are you trying?

Comment: I am running in to similar error while trying to connect to Docker running on another system [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33459411/not-able-to-connect-to-the-docker-server-running-on-another-linux-system)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

How about launching the daemon

```
sudo service docker start
```

should do the trick.

Or

```
sudo docker -d
```

Comment: says that start: Job is already running: docker, but still getting the error from the question title

Comment: `Jonathans-MacBook-Air:~ jonny$ docker -d`
      `flag provided but not defined: -d`
      `See 'docker --help'.`

Comment: @LuísdeSousa "sudo service docker start" worked for me on 16.04, but I had to also add my user to the docker group as straville mentioned.

Answer (score 38):

If you can verify that the docker daemon is running then it may be that your user is not allowed to access docker.

To do this add yourself to the docker group.

```
sudo usermod -aG docker <userid>
```

Remember to do a re-login or otherwise apply/activate the new group permission.

```sh
newgrp docker
```

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 here, I added myself to the docker group. I had to use username instead of user id. I opened another terminal but still get the same result.

Comment: Oh, after adding myself to the group I needed a `sudo service docker restart`

Comment: adding to group and restarting, still got the same result

Comment: @ZeinMiftah Restarting the terminal fixed it for me. Also just to be sure, you can run this:
`sudo groupadd docker`
`sudo gpasswd -a <username> docker`

And verify the changes by looking into `/etc/group` file.

Comment: how do you verify the docker daemon is running?

Comment: @activedecay
Dedepends on the used guest OS
See:https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/    
| For Ubuntu/Debian based distros:
Basic service control methods list, stop, start
Such as: `sudo initctl list` and `sudo service --status-all` |
In RH distros you would use the systemctl command, e.g:
`systemctl status docker.service` -> try restart, in necessary. | Use: ps -ef | grep docker | If those sources say it's "running" you can be better confident that it is running. | HOWEVER possible OS hardening features (AppArmor / SeLinux) can cause trouble.. disable *ONLY* for testing purposes. : ]

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had multiple docker instances running so it didn't know what to attach to. After killing them and restarting, my problem was solved.