# FATA[0000] Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is 'docker -d' running on this host?

Tags: docker

docker version

Client version: 1.4.1

Client API version: 1.16

Go version (client): go1.3.3

Git commit (client): 5bc2ff8/1.4.1

OS/Arch (client): linux/amd64

FATA[0000] Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is 'docker -d' running on this host?

please lte me know y it is giving this error .i m using rhel 6.4

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is 'docker -d' running on this host?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25404597/cannot-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-is-docker-d-running-on-this-host)

Comment: Yes ,any solution for it

Comment: Is docker running on your machine?

Answer (score 0):

As comments suggested probably Docker daemon is not running. AFAIK, docker is not supported for RHEL 6.4. Check [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/installation/rhel/#red-hat-enterprise-linux-6.5-installation):

> Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.5 Installation
>
> You will need 64 bit RHEL 6.5 or later, with a RHEL 6 kernel version
>   2.6.32-431 or higher as this has specific kernel fixes to allow Docker to work.
>
> Docker is available for RHEL6.5 on EPEL. Please note that this package
>   is part of Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux (EPEL), a community
>   effort to create and maintain additional packages for the RHEL
>   distribution. Kernel support
>
> RHEL will only support Docker via the extras channel or EPEL package
>   when running on kernels shipped by the distribution. There are things
>   like namespace changes which will cause issues if one decides to step
>   outside that box and run non-distro kernel packages.
>
> Warning: Please keep your system up to date using yum update and rebooting your system. Keeping your system updated ensures critical security vulnerabilities and severe bugs (such as those found in kernel 2.6.32) are fixed.

Answer (score 0):

with a fresh installation: (notice the sudo at the beginning)

```
$ sudo service docker start
$ sudo docker run hello-world
```

worked for me