# boot2docker resulting in "Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is 'docker -d' running on this host?"

Tags: docker, riak, boot2docker

I'm new to docker and trying to run [this project](https://github.com/hectcastro/docker-riak) on OS X 10.10. Docker is installed through brew and looks good in the basics:

```
➜  docker-riak git:(develop) docker -v
Docker version 1.6.2, build 7c8fca2
➜  docker-riak git:(develop) boot2docker -v
Boot2Docker-cli version: v1.6.2
Git commit: cb2c3bc
```

Here's the error:

```
➜  docker-riak git:(develop) DOCKER_RIAK_AUTOMATIC_CLUSTERING=1 DOCKER_RIAK_CLUSTER_SIZE=5 DOCKER_RIAK_BACKEND=leveldb make start-cluster
./bin/start-cluster.sh
time="2015-06-06T11:21:19-04:00" level=fatal msg="Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is 'docker -d' running on this host?"

Bringing up cluster nodes:

make: *** [start-cluster] Error 1
```

I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25404597/cannot-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-is-docker-d-running-on-this-host) that recommends `sudo docker -d`, but this returns an error:

```
➜  docker-riak git:(develop) docker -d
2015/06/06 11:18:21 This is a client-only binary - running the Docker daemon is not supported.
```

What needs to happen here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the full `docker version` command, and you should see something like this:

`$ docker version
Client version: 1.6.2
Client API version: 1.18
Go version (client): go1.4.2
Git commit (client): 7c8fca2
OS/Arch (client): darwin/amd64
Server version: 1.6.2
Server API version: 1.18
Go version (server): go1.4.2
Git commit (server): 7c8fca2
OS/Arch (server): linux/amd64`

If you don't see all of that, you probably have issues with the connection to boot2docker. Check that you've added the right exports, like this:

`export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.59.103:2376
    export DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/Users/<yourusername>/.boot2docker/certs/boot2docker-vm
    export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1`

See if that helps.

Comment: Thanks. I rain `boot2docker shellinit` and confirmed the export occurred, but I still error out on `docker version` - `client version: 1.6.2
Client API version: 1.18
Go version (client): go1.4.2
Git commit (client): 7c8fca2
OS/Arch (client): darwin/amd64
FATA[0000] Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is 'docker -d' running on this host?`

Comment: Run `export`, and you should see something like this:

`
DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/Users/jonas/.boot2docker/certs/boot2docker-vm
DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.59.103:2376
DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
`

Comment: What the hell? The `shellinit` export doesn't actually show in export. I ran manually and it works. Manually exporting each of these did it. I'd call that a feature request for boot2docker :)

Comment: I have the added the following in my .zshrc file, so after starting boot2docker I can just open a new terminal window and all the exports are correctly set automatically:

`export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://$(boot2docker ip 2>/dev/null):2376

export DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/Users/$USER/.boot2docker/certs/boot2docker-vm

export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1`