# Not able to connect to the Docker server running on another Linux system

Tags: linux, macos, ubuntu, docker, centos

I have Docker installed on two Linux OS on my VirtualBox.
 The VirtualBox is installed on my MAC OS X 10.11 laptop.
The details of the Linux OS versions are as follows:

> **CentOS 7.0 Server** is acting as a Docker client to Docker daemon on **Ubuntu 14.04.03 server**
>
> *I have installed Docker version 1.8.3 on my CentOS 7 OS server which will act as a client for Docker version 1.6.2 installed on Ubuntu 14.04.03 server.*

So CentOS is acting as a Docker client and Ubuntu is acting as a Docker Server daemon. The Ubuntu docker is running on tcp port 2375 on IP address (which I have not given here) as a background daemon ( I found the IP address on Ubuntu by using "ip addr" ...I have a home network setup with wireless router). 

I have also verified that on Ubuntu Linux, Docker is  not listening on socket (which is a default behavior).

Then I setup following environment variable on CentOS -

> export DOCKER_HOST="IP-Address-of-Ubuntu-Server:2375"

Now, I run following command on my CentOS to see if I can detect the Docker Server deamon on Ubuntu Box:

> docker version

I am able to detect the Client Docker version on Centos but not the server part from the Ubuntu after running above command. It shows following instead -

> **Cannot connect to the Docker Daemon. Is 'docker -d' running on this host?**

Additional Notes:

- I have set the SELinux on CentOS using **"setenforce 0"**.
- I have also made following changes to firewalld on the Centos : **firewall-cmd
  --zone=public --add-port=2375/tcp --permanent**
- running **"docker -d"** is of no help here as per my understanding

**What else can I do to be able to detect the Docker server running on another Linux box ?**

Comment: I might be close to solving this. I was able to connect from Ubuntu to Ubuntu using the Docker version 1.6.2 by above approach. It appears that CentOS has a different version of Docker than the Ubuntu (it actually has a higher version of docker). So I am now getting an error - **Error Response from daemon: Client and server don't have same version ( client 1.20 , server 1.18 ).** So I am concluding here that if I can upgrade my Ubuntu machine to docker 1.8.3 (API version 1.20) , then this should work. Unfortunately,  there is no straight forward way to upgrade Ubuntu Docker to 1.8.3.

Comment: It's been a while since you asked, but maybe you still managed to work it out. Maybe my experience will be useful :). I guess you disabled firewall on both CentOS and Ubuntu? You can also disable SELinux on CentOS. I did that, but what really worked for me was disabling DHCP in VirtualBox, setting static IP on Ubuntu and using Internal Network for VMs in VirtualBox.